# Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and i set up the enviroment for that but when i start my app , i'm facing this issue , it keep running endless , i checked with flutter doctor and no issue founds , i also checked the licenses and everything is fine , added android studio to my firewall so it dosn't get blocked , i really have no clue of what is going on, any help is appreciated thankx

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Y8 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
```

Comment: When you run the code in flutter for the first time it will take a long time. So, let it take its time it will execute.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout out this closed GitHub issue regarding this. Unsure what might be the fix for you but you could try `flutter clean` https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47392#issuecomment-578686904

Another person had luck using a USA based VPN https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47392#issuecomment-570338685

And another person had luck updating the compile sdk version for Android
`android/app/build.gradle`

```
+ compileSdkVersion 29 

(...)

defaultConfig {
     (...)
        - targetSdkVersion 28
        + targetSdkVersion 29
    }
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47392#issuecomment-569130814

Comment: should i set up the android sdk also when working on android studio with flutter ?

Comment: You should only have to add what is required by `flutter doctor` for Android toolchain

Comment: checking with flutter doctor it says no issues found , so everything must be fine

Comment: thank you for the answer  i tried all the above answers but none of them worked i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

change

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```